# How can i change object's item value in a loop in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object

I have list of categories. each category is like this:

```
{
 id,
 name,
 info
}
```

I want to loop through the list and change eat category's info after a http get request.
i have searched and read the similar questions but nothing is working. the info always have it's initial value

Comment: Please can you share the code

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Provide the code please, or you can use sandbox for your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the snippet below:

- I am simply looping through the `categories` array and after the data has been fetched I am updating the `info` property.

**NOTE:**

- A common mistake here could be that you're logging the `categories` array before the `async` task is completed.
- So, in the code below if I replace `getData().then(() => console.log(categories));` by `getData(); console.log(categories);` then I would not see the updated value of `info`.

```js
const categories = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "delectus aut autem",
    info: "not fetched",
    url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "quis ut nam facilis",
    info: "not fetched",
    url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/2",
  },
];

const getData = async () => {
  for (let cat of categories) {
    const res = await fetch(cat.url);
    const json = await res.json();
    cat.info = "fetched";
  }
};

getData().then(() => console.log(categories));
```

Comment: @SalehRezaei Please check if this solves your problem, do let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: thanks, you answer is exactly what i needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `forEach` like below:

```
arr.forEach(function(part, index) {
  this[index] = "hello world";
}, arr); // use arr as this
```

Comment: There’s no need to pass `arr` as the `this` value. The callback function already gets called with the iterated array as its third argument. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#parameters